# Does the C-m key combination in emacs generate "\r\n" or just "\n"

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

The emacs docs for C-m key (ie. C-h k C-m) displays the following

```
newline is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

(newline &optional ARG)

Insert a newline, and move to left margin of the new line if it's blank.
If `use-hard-newlines' is non-nil, the newline is marked with the
text-property `hard'.
With ARG, insert that many newlines.
Call `auto-fill-function' if the current column number is greater
than the value of `fill-column' and ARG is nil.
```

But it does not say **newline** is in the context of dos ("\r\n") or unix ("\n").

Comment: When you save the file, newlines are converted accordingly. Functions like `set-buffer-file-coding-system` determine the file encoding standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, Emacs stores a Unix newline, i.e. `"\n"`, in its buffers, similar to what most C programs do when reading text files.  If there is a `"\r"` in an Emacs buffer, it will be displayed as `^M`.

On the other hand, Emacs remembers the newline convention used for each opened file.  If you open a file with `"\r\n"` line breaks, modify it, and save it, then Emacs will convert all newlines back to `"\r\n"`.